# Automate certificate signing in Linux

Tags: certificates, linux, certificate-authority, automation

In a private network I wish to automate signing for new clients/servers.

Something like this:

1. New client is created (dockers & etc)
2. The client create a new private key and a CSR
3. The client send the CSR to a different server which sign it using the CA (???)

Is there a solid solution for providing automated signing services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is: Certificate System manager

Some of the candidates are:

- [DogTag](http://pki.fedoraproject.org/wiki/PKI_Main_Page)
- [Red Hat Certificate System](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/certificate-system) (based on DogTag)
- [EJBCA](https://www.ejbca.org/)
- [OpenCA](http://www.openca.org/)